# Objective-C Command Line Equivalent of ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, command-line

I was just wondering where I should set the values of variables for use in all my methods.
For example, let's say in my .h I say:
    `@property NSString *name;` and then synthesize it in the .m. Where do I assign it a value so in my functions, say `-(NSString *)changeUsername:(NSString *) changes` and `-(void)deleteUsername`, I can access that data?

Comment: Is this a Cocoa application? You could try `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you COULD do so in an initializer for your class and indeed, this would be the approach in C++ or maybe Java. In objective-c, you usually use lazy instantiation, and the best place to do that is in the getter for that property.

If someone assigns a value to the property the setter is called and everything is fine.
If someone asks FOR the value and it has not been set yet (is nil) you can create the object and/or assign a default value in the getter.

```
// Override accessor for name
- (NSString*)name
{
    if (!_name) {
        _name = @"unknown";
    }

    return _name;
}
```

The accessor methods are the only place you should be accessing instance variables directly.

Comment: Is this initializer called first or in the main file should I call this before any other methods of that class?

Comment: When you create your object (from main.m or wherever), you typically call its initializer, by default called init. Ex. MyClass* myclass = [[MyClass alloc] init]; The getter for the property above won't be called until/when it's needed, which is faster.

Comment: nevermind. I looked at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739726/when-to-use-lazy-instantiation-in-ios] and I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is the first thing that gets called in a command line program. Wouldn't you do it there (or somewhere called from `main()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about properties, you must have a class that you're instantiating. That class's designated initializer (`-init` or similar) is the right place to set up your properties and/or instance variables.

The only reason that Cocoa Touch apps defer some initialization tags to `-viewDidLoad` is that view controllers don't load their views when they're initialized and some properties or ivars are related to the view(s) that will be loaded. Those things clearly can't be set up until the view is loaded (or created), so `-viewDidLoad` becomes the best place for setting up those sorts of things.